# Regex: scrub punctuation except if inside a word?

Tags: regex

I'm not great at regex but I have this for removing punctuation from a string.

```
let text = 'a user provided string'
let pattern = /(-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)|[-.,()&$#![\]{}"']+/g;
text.replace(pattern, "$1");
```

I am looking for a way to modify this so that it *keeps* punctuation if inside a word e.g.

- some-hypenated-words
- a_snake_case
- or.even.a.dot.word

should all keep the punctuation. How would I modify it for that?

Comment: What about `double--hyphenated--word`?

Comment: @Nick I'd leave it with single punctuation at first?

Comment: Can you clarify your use case? Why do you need to scrub user strings for punctuation?  Knowing why might give us the ability to suggest cleaner/easier alternatives.

Comment: @Marie I am trying to take a sentence and break it up into words. However the sentence is expected to putatively have punctuation (e.g. parens, commas, etc). Removing _all_ punctuation is now not sufficient as there may be words / tokens with punctuation interspersed (e.g. `some.word`)

Comment: I am curious, why do you need to split a sentence up into words?

Answer (score 1):

One option could be changing the `\d` to `\w` to extend the match to word characters and add a hyphen to the character class in the capturing group.

In the replacement use group 1.

```
(\w+(?:[.,-]\w+)*)|[-.,()&$#![\]{}"']+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p34ehE/1)

If you want to match multiple hyphens, commas or dots you could repeat the character class `[.,-]+`